# DataAnnotations on public fields vs properties in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Why don't DataAnnotations work on public fields? Example:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Title; // { get; set; }
    }
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
     return View(new Models.Product() { Title = "why no love?" });
}

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title) // will return 'Title' if field, or 'Name' if property
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)
```

If Title is a field, then the Display attribute seems to have no effect. If Title is changed to a property, it works as expected as displays "Name".

It would seem easy in this example to just change to a property, but I am trying to use the types from F# where they get compiled to a class with fields and not properties.

This was tested in ASP.NET 4 and MVC RC 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why DataAnnotations do not work with fields is because the reflection-like mechanism that is used to retrieve the attributes (`TypeDescriptor`) only supports properties.

While it would not be easy, we could look into making this work with fields if there is enough demand.

Comment: The JSON serializer in MVC returns both the fields and properties, not sure why fields are treated differently for annotations.

Comment: That's a mismatch between parts of the .NET framework. DataAnnotations is only supported on properties by default (though you could write a MetadataProvider that could inspect fields as well). On the other hand JavaScript serialization supports both fields and properties. That's just the way it is right now.