# Data Annotation only validates when using get accessor on field

Tags: c#, validation, attributes, data-annotations

When validating data annotations, why does it only seem to validate (correctly) when using a get accessor on the property you want to validate?

Given the example below, the `Name` property will always be considered valid, even though it is unassigned, however the `Address` property will only be considered valid if it assigned a non-empty string value, all because it's using a `get` accessor. Why is this?

Surely `TryValidateObject` will basically just use `test.Address` to access the value whether it's through a get accessor or not.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var _errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
            test, new ValidationContext(test), _errors, true);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    [Required]
    public string Name; // Returns true even when unassigned / null / empty string

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; } // Only returns true when assigned a non-empty string
}
```

Comment: There could be a correlation between the autogenerated properties which are generated by the compiler if you use {get;}

I did a small research and if I'm right the compiler build an private property for {get}

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but maybe because your Name is not a property, but a public field. So one could assume the logic behind the validators only tries to get the value of properties...and no one should write a public field anyway

Comment: @MichaelFaisst Interesting, you could be right. Seems strange that the required attribute can still be used on a public field even though it doesn't seem to work with them.

Comment: yep, msdn says that the required attributes can also target fields, but the Validator-Class ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) states that it "can be used to validate objects, properties, and methods"...so I'm not sure^^

Comment: See this answer from a (now former) MS employee: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4308791/1220550

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `Validator.TryValidateObject` will only check *properties* and class-level annotations, but your `Name` is a field, not a property (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that documentation of `Validator` class does not mention fields). If you apply any other attribute (like `Range`) to a field - it also won't work with `Validator.TryValidateObject`. The reason why `RequiredAttribute` can be applied to a field is because `RequiredAttribute` is an entity on it's own and is not related\tied to Validator class in any way. Any other validation mechanism *can* validate public fields, it's just specific `Validator` class which does not.